# How to prove $1+{x\over 2}-{x^2 \over 8}<\sqrt{1+x}$ for all $x>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, taylor-expansion

How to prove $1+(1/2)x-(1/8)x^2<\sqrt{1+x}$ for $x>0$ by Taylor Expansions up to $n$ order or Mean Value Theorem? I tried to apply MVT on $\sqrt{1+x}$ and get $\displaystyle \sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+\xi}}x$ for $\xi\in (0,x)$. How to do next?

Comment: Why don't you try derivative? Is it not allowed?

Comment: Can derivative fully solve this? btw This is an exercise from a Taylor expansion chapter in Fitzpatrick's text.

Comment: Yeah sure, you can have a try :)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to avoid Taylor series, but it is worth noting how simple this is if you use them: for $0<x<1$, the LHS is the first 3 terms of an alternating series which converges to the RHS, and in general the partial sums of an alternating series are alternately above and below the limit.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood wow, never learnt it before! Can you say more about this?

Comment: @Cuteboy I have trouble in using derivative way. $\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}x$, how to solve $f'(x)=0$?

Comment: @Eric Let $f'(x)=0$, then you can move the sqaured term to the left, then take the quadratic power of both sides, then you are in fact solving a polynomial problem.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{\left(\sqrt{x+1}\right)'''_{x=\xi}x^3}{6}$$ and since $\left(\sqrt{x+1}\right)'''>0$ for all $x>0$, we are done!

A proof without Taylor series.

If $1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}<0$ or $x>2+2\sqrt3$ then  it's obvious.

But for $0<x\leq2+2\sqrt3$ it's enough to prove that
$$(x^2-4x-8)^2<64(1+x)$$ or
$$x^3(x-8)<0.$$
Done!

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt {1+x}\;.$ For $x>0$ we have $$f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+x^2f''(y)/2$$ where $0<y<x.$ We have $f(0)=1$ and $f'(0)=1/2.$ We have $$f''(y)=-\frac {1}{4(1+y)^{3/2}}>-\frac {1}{4}  .$$ So  $\sqrt {1+x}=f(x)=1+x/2-x^2f''(y)/2>1+x/2-x^2/8.$

Answer (score 2):

*Taylor's formula* isn't really required:

Set $\;f(x)=1+\dfrac x2-\dfrac{x^2}8$, $\;g(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$. We have
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\frac12-\frac x4,&g'(x)&=\frac1{2\sqrt{1+x}},\\
f''(x)&=-\frac 14,&g''(x)&=-\frac1{4(1+x)^{3/2}}.
\end{align}
Observe that $\;f(0)=g(0)=1$, $\;f'(0)=g'(0)=\dfrac12$, $\;f''(0)=g''(0)=-\dfrac14$, and that $f''(x)<g''(x)< 0$ for all $x>0$.

A well-known corollary of the *mean Value theorem* ensures first that $f'(x)<g'(x)$, and thence that $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: The race drivers are neck to neck at $0$ starting point, but from that point on driver $g$ acceleration is STRICTLY GREATER than driver $f$. (+1 )

Comment: @Benard I feel those problems of proving inequalities by MVT or Taylor is usually somewhat  adhoc or needs the "intelligence". Theoretically speaking, is the traditional way using derivatives to prove the inequality always doable?

Comment: @Eric: Using derivatives is just a special way to formulate the well-known corollary of the MVT I mention (inequality between derivatives + inequality between initial values  implies inequality between functions). It can be used as long as you can prove inequalities between derivatives. However some problems can be harder and require Taylor with estimates of the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to prove the inequality without using Taylor expansion. Let
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac12x. $$
Then
$$ f'(x)=-\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{1+x})^3}+\frac12>0, \text{ for } x>0 $$
namely $f(x)$ is increasing for $x>0$. So
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac12x>1$$
or
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}>1-\frac12x. $$
Integrating from $0$ to $x$ gives
$$ \int_0^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}}dt>\int_0^x(1-\frac12t)dt $$
from which one has
$$ \sqrt{1+x}>1+\frac12x-\frac18x^2. $$

Answer (score 1):

As requested, *with* Taylor series. Consider $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$. [It's well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) that $f$ has a Taylor series centred at $0$ with radius of convergence $1$, which begins 
$$f(x) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{k}x^{k} = 1+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{8}x^{2}+\ldots$$
You can get an exact expression for the coefficients (it's something like $c_{k} = \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k+1}{2k \choose k}$), but all that matters is that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|c_{k}|$ converges, the coefficients are alternating in sign, and $|c_k x^k|$ forms a decreasing sequence. Taylors theorem tells us that for all $x \in (0,1)$, 
$$f(x) - \sum_{k=0}^{n}c_{k}x^{k}= c_{n+1}\xi^{n+1}$$
for some $\xi \in (0,1)$ depending on $x$. In any case, this difference is bounded above (taking the modulus) by $|c_{n+1}|$, independently of $\xi$. So for every $x\in(0,1)$, 
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{k}x^{k}$$
You can also readily see that for $k>0$, $c_{k} = (-1)^{k+1}|c_{k}|$ - that is, the coefficients alternate. I claim that this implies that, for every $n>0$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}c_{k}x^{k}\le \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{k}x^{k} \le \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}c_{k}x^{k}$$
To see this, write
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}c_{k}x^{k} = 1+\left(|c_{1}|x^{1} - |c_{2}|x^{2}\right) + \ldots + \left(|c_{2n-1}|x^{2n-1}-|c_{2n}|x^{2n}\right) $$ 
which is a sum of positive terms, and hence positive for every $n$. That is, the sequence $S_{n}= \sum_{k=0}^{2n}c_{k}x^{k}$ is increasing and tends to $f(x)$. So $S_{n}\le f(x)$ for all $n$ (and in fact the inequality is strict). Similarly, 
$$T_{n} := \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}c_{k}x^{k} = 1+|c_{1}|x^{1} - (|c_{2}|x^{2} - |c_{3}|x^{3}) - \ldots - (|c_{2n}|x^{2n}-|c_{2n+1}|x^{2n+1} $$ 
is a *decreasing* sequence which tends to $f(x)$. So $T_{n}>f(x)$ for all $n$. Your question is the particular case of the lower bound when $n=1$.